# functional programming way to flat arrays in javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very new in javascript and I am trying to flatten attribute in an object which save in an array of objects.

```
[
 {
  addr: addrvalue1,
  events: [1,2],
 },
 {
  addr: addrvalue2,
  events: [1],
 }
]
```

I want to convert objects above to

```
[{
 addr: addrvalue1,
 events: 1,
}
{
 addr: addrvalue1,
 events: 2,
}
{
 addr: addrvalue2,
 events: 1,
}]
```

And then sort them by event value, so they will finally be like

```
[{
     addr: addrvalue1,
     events: 1,
    }
{
     addr: addrvalue2,
     events: 1,
    }
    {
     addr: addrvalue1,
     events: 2,
    }
]
```

For now I am using multiple for-loops for to do this, but I think there would be some more elegant way doing this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) with [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat)

```js
const data = [{
    addr: 111,
    events: [1, 2],
  },
  {
    addr: 222,
    events: [1],
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, {addr, events})=>{
  return acc.concat(events.map(item=>({addr, events: item})));
}, []);

console.log(result.sort((a,b)=>a.events-b.events));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate the objects and flatten the results, and an internal [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the arrays of event objects. Then you can sort them by the event.

```js
const data = [{"addr":"addrvalue1","events":[1,2]},{"addr":"addrvalue2","events":[1]}]

const result = data.flatMap(({ addr, events }) => events.map(event => ({
    event,
    addr
  })))
  .sort((o1, o2) => o1.event - o2.event)
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Good use of flatMap

Comment: Because flatMap is not supported by IE and Edge. If you need a support for those browsers use @kemicofa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var output=[],
    data=[
 {
  addr: "addrvalue1",
  events: [1,2],
 },
 {
  addr: "addrvalue2",
  events: [1],
 }
]
for(obj of data){
  for(i in obj.events){
    output.push({addr:obj.addr,events:parseInt(i)+1})
  }
}
output.sort(function(a,b){return a.events-b.events})
console.log(output)
```

I hope it will helps :)